# Change the value of an order

Tags: python, random, shutdown, os.system

I'm trying to change the value of a command on each run.
For this I tried a prototype like this:

```
import os
import random
from random import random

class testShutDown :

    ticks = random.randint(10,100)
    os.system("shutdown /s /t {ticks}")
```

According to me, with each execution of the code, the computer must shut down randomly between 10 and 100 seconds.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work... I hope someone can help me solve this problem which seems simple to me, but not for me.

Comment: os.system(f"shutdown /s /t {ticks}")
where f is to tell compiler that string contains formats e.g. variable

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the f in f-string?

```
f"shutdown /s /t {ticks}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import random
from random import random

class testShutDown :

    ticks = random.randint(10,100)
    os.system(f"shutdown /s /t {ticks}")
```

i think u forgot to add `f` before string try this.
f tells that the string contains a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `f` for strings substitution. For example,

```
>>> name = "apple"
>>> f"My test name is {name}."
'My test name is apple.'
```

Therefore the solution is to modify the `os` line to this:

```
os.system(f"shutdown /s /t {ticks}")
```

Alternatively, you can use the `format` function:

```
os.system('shutdown /s /t {}'.format(ticks))
```

Also, you should just use `import random` instead of `from random import random`.